# Find a general solution to Euler's equation for an integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

The question asks me to find the general solution to Euler's equation for:

$$\int^b_ay'^2-8xy+x \, dx.$$

How would one find such a solution? My textbook does not do a very good job of explaining how to solve such a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$L(x, y, y') = y'^2 - 8xy + x$$
Then the Euler equation tells us that
$$J[y] = \int_a^b L(x,y,y') \, dx$$ has an extremum when
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 0$$
We can easily calculate these derivatives given $L$:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'} = 2y' \implies \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 2y''$$
and
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = -8x$$
Hence, $J[y]$ has an extremum when:

$$2y'' + 8x = 0$$

Integrating twice, we get:

$$y = -\frac23 x^3 + c_1x + c_2$$

Now, if given boundary conditions (like $y(a) = y_0, y(b) = y_1$), you could determine the values for the constants $c_1, c_2$.

The above expression for $y$ is what they mean when they say to *find a solution to the euler equation*.

It's poor (but common) language to say this, when they really mean *find the function $y(x)$ that extremizes the given integral by solving the corresponding euler equation*

Comment: That was a very well-explained solution. Thank you. However, how can we be sure that the answer is a minima and not a maxima?

Comment: @Mathmaniac: For this problem, that fact is negligible. However, in general, you may be able to figure it out by plugging $y$ and $y'$ back into the integral, and integrating the expression. Then repeat this again choosing some arbitrary (but different than $y$) function $y_1$. You can compare the values to test for the type of extrema. Since we know the $y$ given by the Euler equation is extremal, if $J[y_1] < J[y]$, then $y$ is a maximum. If $J[y_1] > J[y]$, then $y$ is a minimum.

Comment: There may be better methods to doing this as well, but that should work. Note that $y_1$ need not be complicated (indeed, it could be the zero function if the problem allows that)